# Maximizing a quartic polynomial over an interval

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, karush-kuhn-tucker

Given $c > 0$ and $u > l > 0$, $$ \max_{x \in \Bbb R} \, \left( 1 - 2 c x^2 \right)^2 \quad \text{subject to} \quad l \leq x \leq u $$
Can the maximum value be found in terms of $l$ or $u$?

---

**My try:**

One can write the problem as follows:
$$
\min_{
\begin{aligned}
x&> 0\\
 x- l &\geq 0\\
 u -x &\geq 0
\end{aligned}
} -(1-2cx^2)^2
$$
and define Lagrange multiplier $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3 \geq 0$ and consider 8 different situations for $\lambda$'s.

**Question**

Is there a hacky way of solving the above without considering constrained optimization?

Comment: You mean you want to find the value of c that optimizes the value of the polynomial?

Comment: Consider the variations of $1-2cx^2$. When it's positive the max of the square is the max of $1-2cx^2$. When it's negative you will have to find the minimum. First do that without constraints. Then either the optimum is inside $(l,u)$ and then the constraints are not important, or on the border, and then depending on a condition on $c$ it's either $l$ or $u$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the constraint $0<l≤x≤u$, we have:

$$1-2cu^2≤1-2cx^2≤1-2cl^2$$

This implies that,

$$
\begin{align}\max \left\{\left(1-2cx^2\right)^2\wedge 0<l≤x≤u\right\}=\max\left\{\left(1-2cu^2\right)^2,\;\left(1-2cl^2\right)^2\right\}\end{align}
$$

Comment: +1 Of course. I forgot the "$0<$" in $0<l\le x\le u$, an this makes things much simpler as there is no local max.